# setTextSize(float) not supported in remote TextView?

Tags: android, android-widget

I'm trying to set the text size of a remote TextView in a Widget like so:

```
RemoteViews rv = new RemoteViews(mContext.getPackageName(), layoutId);
rv.setFloat(R.id.subject, "setTextSize", 10f);
```

While I can set other attributes like the text color or change the view's visibility, when using the setTextSize the inflation fails with the following error message (no stack trace):

```
Error inflating RemoteViews at position: 1, using loading view instead
android.widget.RemoteViews$ActionException:
view: android.widget.TextView doesn't have method: setTextSize (float)
```

setTextSize(float) has the @RemotableViewMethod annotation so it should be supported but the method isn't even found (there's a difference between the "doesn't have method" and the "not supported" error).

Why wouldn't it find the method when it's clearly there?
Introducing the setTextViewTextSize() method for RemoteViews in API 16 could be an indicator that there's something wrong with my approach?
Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use int type in third parameter. So, remove the 'f' which makes it an explicit float.

```
rv.setFloat(R.id.subject, "setTextSize", 10);
```

Comment: This really works even if I have no clue why it does! I guess you'd have to dig deep into the AOSP source to find the reason why the float doesn't work while the int does. Thank you anyway!